# can't load file in relative path in HTML using href

Tags: html, vue.js, href

I'm trying to give a hyperlink to a local pdf file. I found out if I use an absolute path, my site will open the pdf with a new tab. However, when I try to use a relative path, the console gives a warning "No match found for location with path "

This work:

```
<a href="E\Project\assets\test.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

This doesn't work

```
<a href="..\assets\test.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

Comment: Are you using router? The URL is handled by router in VueJS, and it has multiple working modes.

Comment: I was hoping not to use the router because I have a lot of pdf files. I was hoping the anchor tag and href will open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Two dots `..` means go one folder up, translating it to an absolute link would mean it's looking for `E\assets\test.pdf`. Try changing it to `.\assets\test.pdf`.

Comment: I do want to use the .. because the vue file I was working on is not at the same level as assets.  The problem is this href leads to localhost:8080/path rather than the true file path.

Comment: @chuhuichen my bad. Maybe try `.\..\assets\test.pdf`